# как поменять направление движения обьекта при столкновении с чем-либо Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

я смог прописать движение мячика

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Vector : MonoBehaviour{

    public Vector2 direction;
    public float speed;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.Translate(direction.normalized * speed);
    }
}
```

хотел сделать так, чтобы при контакте со стенами он изменял направление по x или y, но не получилось.
По идее нужно сделать так:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider other)
    {
     if (other.tag == "Frontier")
        {
            direction = direction.normalized * speed * -1;
        }
```

но в теле if должно быть что-то другое, изменяющее движение только по y, да и то,что есть не работает

Comment: Почему бы не использовать физику Unity? Физический движок сам просчитает что и куда должно отскакивать. А раз уж Вы используете OnTriggerEnter2D, значит на шарике и стенах есть коллайдеры - это уже часть движка физики. Более того, объекты с коллайдерами крайне не рекомендуется перемещать с помощью прямого задания положения через методы и свойств Transform

Answer (score 2):

Сначала надо взять ссылку на объект, и тогда всё должно заработать.
(Правда не совсем понимаю, как здесь используется Vector2 direction.)

```
public float speed;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    // colliderWith - здесь, ссылка на игровой тот объект, который столкнулся 
    // с объектом, к которому подключен скрипт 
    // (colliderWith - стена
    //  other - шар, направление которого надо изменить)

    GameObject colliderWith = other.gameObject;
    if (colliderWith.tag == "Frontier") {
        speed *= -1;
    } 
}
```